# What is the value of $x$ such that $\frac{\text{d}^2y}{\text{d}x^2}=0$ where $\frac{\text{d}y}{\text{d}x}=-ae^{-bx}y-cy+d$?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

How can you find the values of $x$ such that

$$\frac{\text{d}^2y(x)}{\text{d}x^2}=0$$

where

$$\frac{\text{d}y}{\text{d}x}=-ae^{-bx}y-cy+d$$
with
$$y(0)=y_0$$
and
$$a,b,c,d>0$$
If it helps I can approximate $b\approx c$, I am currently working on an solution that utilises that fact but it seems to have failed. I will post any advances I make but currently I am stumped.
The DE isn't particularly nicely solvable as you end up with exponential integrals. This problem is also  equivalent to maximising the first derivative of $y$, as I know this equation produces a sigmoid shape. I also would not mind an approximation for the solutions of $x$.

My workings:

If we define
$$f(x)=ae^{-bx}+c$$
and
$$g(x)=e^{\int f(x) \Bbb dx}$$
then we find
$$\frac{\text{d}y}{\text{d}x}=d\frac{\text{d}}{\text{d}x}
\left(
\frac{d}{g(x)}
\int_0^x g(s)\text{d}s
\right)
$$
Then by differentiating once and setting it equal to zero we find the problem reduces to solving
$$g^2g'+gg''\int_0^x g(s) \Bbb d s=2g'^2\int_0^x g(s) \Bbb d s$$
where primes indicate differentiation.

Comment: This is a first-order linear ordinary differential equation, there is a general method for this type of equation. See [wikipedia for example](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_differential_equation#First-order_equation_with_variable_coefficients).

Comment: @user37238: Yes, I am aware of that. I have expanded my question slightly .

Comment: The answer falls out from the method of integrating factors as you've demonstrated. Whether that solution is elementary is another question (it probably isn't).

Comment: @Ian: I have edited the title and body to make the question more specific. It is no longer a question where the answer is simply 'use integrating factors'!

Comment: When you say solve $\frac{d^2 y}{dx^2} = 0$, do you mean find a $y$ satisfying the other properties which is identically zero, or find an $x$ where $\frac{d^2 y}{dx^2}(x)=0$? The former is probably impossible. The latter might be possible.

Comment: @Ian: I mean the latter, many thanks for helping me make this question more presentable!

Comment: @Ian: This is what i'm working on, you can see my attempt at this in body of the question. The problem effectively is that it's a pain to deal with an integral of the form $\int \exp{\exp{(-x)}}$

Comment: OK. Now a suggestion: don't use indefinite integrals. In fact you very rarely want to use indefinite integrals, they're just a convenient shorthand in simple problems. Instead, you should make all your integrals from $0$ to $x$.

Comment: @Ian: I agree, I will get back to this asap, I need to sign off right now unfortunately.

Comment: I solved this D.E. so if you need $y(x)$, i'll give you the formula implicitly

Comment: @mwomath: Yes I would love to see that!

Comment: @Freeman: You want to find where point of inflection occurs on the sigmoid curve whose differential equation is $\frac {dy}{dx}=−a e^{−bx} y−cy+d, $ right?

Comment: @Narasimham: Indeed, yes I do.

Comment: If you are free to pick $y_0$ then we can tune this value such that $x=0$ becomes the solution. This is the case if $y_0 = \frac{(a+c)d}{(a+c)^2 + a b}$.

Comment: why don't you use implicit differentiation? Set $\frac{\text{d}y}{\text{d}x}= f(x,y)$. Then using implicit differentiation we have $$ -F_x / F_y $$ which gives second derivative with respect to x. Then substitute $y_0 and x_0$ then proceed. You need to consider an intervals where y can be defined as function of x, according to implicit function theorem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$\frac{dy}{dx}=-ae^{-bx}y-cy+d$$

Multiplying both sides by $e^{bx}$ and rewrite the D.E to be in the form

$$(ay+(cy-d)e^{bx})dx+e^{bx}dy=0$$

Let $M(x,y)=ay+(cy-d)e^{bx} \Rightarrow M_y=a+ce^{bx}$, and
$N(x,y)=e^{bx} \Rightarrow N_x=be^{bx}$, which mean that the D.E. is not exact.

Let find an appropriate integrating factor $\mu(x)$ (depends only on $x$) for the which the D.E. is exact

$$\frac{d\mu}{\mu}=\frac{M_y-N_x}{N}=\frac{a+ce^{bx}-be^{bx}}{e^{bx}}=ae^{-bx}+c-b$$

Thus, $$\ln \mu(x)= -\frac{a}{b}e^{-bx}+(c-b)x\Rightarrow\mu(x) =e^{-\frac{a}{b}e^{-bx}}\cdot e^{(c-b)x}$$

Multiplying both sides of (1), by $\mu(x)$ we get an exact D.E.

So that, let $\phi(x,y)$ be a solution of the D.E. such that

$\frac{\partial \phi}{\partial y}=N(x,y)=e^{-\frac{a}{b}e^{-bx}}\cdot e^{(c-b)x} \cdot e^{bx}=e^{-\frac{a}{b}e^{-bx}}\cdot e^{cx} \Rightarrow \phi(x,y)=e^{-\frac{a}{b}e^{-bx}}\cdot e^{cx}y+h(x)$

ut since $\phi_x=M(x,y)$, we get that $$
e^{ - {\textstyle{a \over b}}e^{ - bx} } e^{cx} \left( {c + ae^{ - bx} } \right)
y+h'(x)= 
aye^{ - {\textstyle{a \over b}}e^{ - bx} } e^{\left( {c - b} \right)x}  + \left( {cy - d} \right)e^{ - {\textstyle{a \over b}}e^{ - bx} } e^{cx} 
$$

$$\Rightarrow h'(x)=-d
e^{ - {\textstyle{a \over b}}e^{ - bx} } e^{cx} 
\Rightarrow  h(x)=-d\int{e^{ - {\textstyle{a \over b}}e^{ - bx} } e^{cx}  dx}$$

Hence, $$\phi(x,y)=e^{-\frac{a}{b}e^{-bx}}\cdot e^{cx}y-d\int{e^{ - {\textstyle{a \over b}}e^{ - bx} } e^{cx}  dx}=C$$ where, $C$ is constant

Comment: The question is not to solve the original first order DE, it is to find the values of $x$ where the second derivative of the solution vanishes.

Comment: This is $\phi(x,y)=g(x)y(x)-d\int g(x)\,dx$, i.e. gives the same expression for $y$ as in the OP.

Comment: Yes, but the man whose ask the question ask me to see the solution. Read the comment above.

Comment: @mwomath: Many thanks for posting this, Ian is right that the question is as he states. however I did want to see what you had done, so many thanks for supplying your workings.

Comment: The integral given in the solution is from o to x.  In this form, if $x = 0$, the term is zero.  This allows you to solve for $C$.

Comment: Indeed, we can solve it directly: rewrite the eq as $y'+(ae^{-bx}+c)y=d$ which is linear eq. with $p(x)=ae^{-bx}+c$ and $g(x)=d$. As special case if d =0 then the required solution (about inflection points) become easy.

Answer (score 0):

There is no need to integrate or use boundary conditions thereby introducing new constants.  Just differentiate once, set second derivative to zero, algebraically simplify it to get an implicit relation between $x , y$ as follows:

$$ \frac{dy}{dx}=-ae^{-bx}y-cy+d \tag{1} $$

Let $ e^{b\,x}= u $ so that $ u{'}= b\, u.$ Primes denote differentiation with respect to x. $ a,b,c,d $ are constants. $ y= y _{PI} $ for short.

$ y^{''}$ vanishes when  $ y^{'}$ is an extremum. Also if  $ y^{'}$ is in a quotient form, then  using Quotient Rule,

$$ y^{'}= (\dfrac pq)^{'} =  \dfrac {q p ^{'}-q^{'} p  }{q^2} = 0\rightarrow \frac pq =  \frac {p^{'}}{q^{'}} $$

$$ \dfrac{-a y -cyu+du}{u} =\dfrac{-ay^{'}- c ( y^{'}u + y u^2 b) + dub}{ub}  \tag{2} $$

Removing negative sign

$$ \dfrac{a y + cyu-du}{u} =\dfrac{ay^{'}+ c ( y^{'} u + y u^2 b) -dub }{ub}  $$

$$ aby - bcyu = a y^{'} + c u ( y^{'} + buy) \tag{3}$$

$$ by (a- c u^2 -cu )= y^{'} (a+ c u) $$

Plugging in from (1)

$$ by (a- c u^2 -cu )= ( -a y/u-c y+d ) (a+ c u) \tag{4}$$

is the required implicit function  $ f(x,y_{PI})= 0 $ for inflection point loci which may include them in the sigmoid plot. To find specific $x$ values cubic equations have to be  solved further.

EDIT 1:

For a special case taking values $ a = 1, c = d =0,$  all $x_{PI}$ are on a line parallel to y-axis at a distance of $$ x_{PI}= -\frac{log (b)}{b}. $$

From mwomath's expression

$$ y = C Exp[ \frac{-e^{-b x}}{b}] $$

EDIT 1:

Giving a simpler example to identify inflection locus of a given DE:

$$ y' = - x\, y $$

Integrating, you get

$$ y = C e^{\frac{-x^2}{2}} $$

which is a Gaussian probability curve of variable maximum height $C.$

Take next (second order) derivative and eliminate $y'$ to get:

$$ y '' = y ( 1- x^2) $$

for inflection locus, $ y^{''}=0. $

Plotting its graph of the curve with several values for $C$ you can see two neat lines parallel to y-axis $$ x = \pm 1, $$ each passing through the inflection point of each corresponding curve on either side.

Comment: Thank you for this answer, I don't suppose you could expand on your workings from (1) to (2) and define 'quotient form' and v?

Comment: I had considered this, but without a solution for $y(x)$ could you explain how we can determine $x$ values here?

Comment: As desired by you I have found x for a special case. You can superimpose it on the integrand graph and see that perhaps all S- shaped curves have a PI on the line parallel to y-axis.

Comment: Thank you for your edit. Apologies for my slowness, but I am struggling to see how solving this implicit function for a $y,x$ relation helps us identify the correct values of $x$?

Comment: As desired by you I have found x for a special case. You can superimpose it on the integrand graph and see that perhaps all S- shaped curves have a PI on the line parallel to y-axis. For some constants  I think you should plot the curves $  (x,y)  $ together with $(x_{PI}, y ).$

Comment: Ok, I'm not sure what you mean by 'S shaped curve' and 'PI'. Also I special case is not really what i'm looking for, as $a,b,c,d>0$. I have read your previous comment, I was hoping for a short explanation of your reasoning with respect to my last comment.

Comment: @Freeman S shape I meant the same sigmoid curve. By PI I mean "point of inflection". I have to tell you, it leads you nowhere if you clutter up so many constants.I assumed simple cases. What I got is an implicit form of $ (x_{PI},y) not (x,y)$. I must leave now..

Comment: Hope it is clear after plotting them together.

Comment: Only *superimposed/combined  plotting*  will convince you visibly about correctness of your solution.

Comment: 'As desired by you I have found x for a special case.', a special case is of no use to me and it not what I meant by 'approximate solution', many thanks however.

Comment: The general procedure is the same as shown, valid  in all cases..